# RSA key format is not supported when trying to read from .env

Tags: python, django, secret-key

I'm trying to place this RSA key in my env file

settings.py

```
DJPADDLE_PUBLIC_KEY = '''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
abcdefghijklmnoopasdasdhjahsdjahsdjkahsjdhasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasdaasda
abcdefghijklmnoopasdasdhjahsdjahsdjkahsjdhasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasdaasda
abcdefghijk==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'''
```

.env

```
DJPADDLE_PUBLIC_KEY=-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
abcdefghijklmnoopasdasdhjahsdjahsdjkahsjdhasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasdaasda
abcdefghijklmnoopasdasdhjahsdjahsdjkahsjdhasdsadasdasdasdasdasdasdaasda
abcdefghijk==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

my settings.py

```
from decouple import config

    DJPADDLE_PUBLIC_KEY = config('DJPADDLE_PUBLIC_KEY')
```

but i get this error

```
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: failed to convert 'DJPADDLE_PUBLIC_KEY'; original message: RSA key format is not supported
```

Traceback

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djpaddle/settings.py", line 26, in <module>
    DJPADDLE_KEY = convert_pubkey_to_rsa(DJPADDLE_PUBLIC_KEY)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djpaddle/utils.py", line 25, in convert_pubkey_to_rsa
    return RSA.importKey(public_key_der)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 785, in import_key
    raise ValueError("RSA key format is not supported")
ValueError: RSA key format is not supported
```

Comment: Are you sure the environment variable is really exported to the process? Django doesn't automatically read .env files.

Comment: @HåkenLid i have other keys in my env which are being detected and no errors

Comment: Is it decouple or djpaddle that raises the exception? Please include the traceback.

Comment: This is the error i'm getting now ' django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: failed to convert 'DJPADDLE_PUBLIC_KEY'; original message: RSA key format is not supported'

Comment: still getting the same error. Sorry i had gotten the 'your question has too much code error' when i tried to update the question, the traceback is there now.

Comment: Looks like djpaddle is rather picky with the exact format of the PUBLIC_KEY variable. Since it worked properly when you had the key in the settings.py file, it's likely that decouple is messing it up. Maybe multiline variables in .env files are not supported?

Comment: You should ask this question on the decouple github issue tracker. It looks to me that decouple simply does not support multiline variables in .env files (it reads the file line by line, and ignores lines that it can't parse). On the other hand dj-paddle _only_ accepts a multiline variable here.

Comment: Hello, how do you solve your problem please ?

Comment: I know this is old but did you solve the issue?